# DOMDocument returns empty data

Tags: php, html, dom, web-scraping

I am not getting into this if loop. I have a copy of the code exactly on another virtual server with the same PHP version and this gets in the loop and returns the result from CURL using a webpage as a resource. Is there something I am missing that is wrong with the code snip (I am trying to be succinct, but there is more code). Any related tips would be helpful.

```
class News extends General
{
    public $CU;


    // Constructor
    public function __construct()
    {
     $this->CU = new CURL();
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($this->CU->Response['Body']);
     $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    }

        $result_list = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 's-search-results')]//div[contains(@class, 's-result-item')]//h2//a");
        $price_list =  $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 's-search-results')]//div[contains(@class, 's-result-item')]//span[contains(@data-a-color, 'base')]//span[contains(@class, 'a-offscreen')]");



            if($result_list->length > 0 && $result_list->length==$price_list->length) 
            {
                ECHO "In the loop";
            }
}
```

Comment: It would probably need to see the web page you are using as all I can see if that the two XPath expressions don't return the same lengths of data.

Comment: Is there anything that looks off I am missing?

Comment: what is strange is this works (I had omitted)  $result_it = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 's-result-item')]"); it is almost like on this virtual server I can't send too many "nodes"